# Problema com animação de um algoritmo de ordenação

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, bubblesort

Boa noite, estou querendo fazer uma simples animação em barras do algoritmo de ordenação ***bubblesort*** utilizando *canvas* do *html* em conjunto com *javascript* mas por algum motivo as barras não trocam de posição, como se não tivesse o bubble. O que deixei passar ou implementei errado? Obrigado

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id ="bubble" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #c6c6c6"></canvas>
        <>

            function random(min, max) {
                return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
            }

            var Barra = function(){
                let numero
                let posX
                let posY
                let altura
                let largura
                let ctx

                this.setNumero = function(_numero){
                    this.numero = _numero
                }

                this.setPosX = function(_posX){
                    this.posX = _posX
                }

                this.setPosY = function(_posY){
                    this.posY = _posY
                }

                this.setAltura = function(_altura){
                    this.altura = _altura
                }

                this.setLargura = function(_largura){
                    this.largura = _largura 
                }

                this.setCtx = function(){
                    this.ctx = c.getContext("2d")
                }                
            }

            let c = document.getElementById("bubble")

            let vet = []
            let soma = 0
            for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
                vet[i] = new Barra()
                let num = Math.floor(random(1,100))
                vet[i].setNumero(num)
                vet[i].setPosX(soma)
                soma += 10
                vet[i].setPosY(0)
                vet[i].setAltura(num + 100)
                vet[i].setLargura(50)
                vet[i].setCtx()
                vet[i].ctx.fillStyle = "red"
                vet[i].ctx.fillRect(vet[i].posX,vet[i].posY,vet[i].largura,vet[i].altura)
            }

            function bubble(vet){
                let aux = 0 
                for(let i = 0; i < vet.length; i++){
                    for(let j = 0; j < (vet.length - 1); j++){
                        if(vet[j].numero > vet[j + 1].numero){                    
                            vet[j].posX = vet[j].posX
                            vet[j + 1].posX = vet[j + 1]
                            vet[j].ctx.fillRect(vet[j].posX,vet[j].posY,vet[j].largura,vet[j].altura)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            bubble(vet)
        </>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No seu código local vc deixou mesmos as tags do script vazias ? `<>` e aqui `</>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problema visual

No navegador o JavaScript executa o código em contexto e thread único(Single Thread) e o canvas não dispõe de um método para forçar atualizações visuais(tipo redraw), isso implica que qualquer alteração gráfica que você faça no contexto de um objeto `canvas` dentro de um laço só será exibida depois que o laço for concluído.

No seu código também havia tags vazias `<>` e `</>` que provavelmente são as tags `<script>` e `</script>`.

## Solução Visual

Para contornar essa característica da linguagem você pode remodelar o seu código para que ao invés de depender de um laço `for` para realizar operações gráficas, essas operações sejam feitas reiteradamente dentro de uma requisição por quadros de animação. Essa requisição é feita pelo método ['window.requestAnimationFrame()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)

O método ['window.requestAnimationFrame()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)  informa ao navegador que deseja-se realizar uma animação e requer que o navegador chame uma função específica para atualizar um quadro de animação antes da próxima repintura.

```js
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var Barra = function() {
    let numero
    let posX
    let posY
    let altura
    let largura
    let ctx

    this.setNumero = function(_numero) {
        this.numero = _numero
    }

    this.setPosX = function(_posX) {
        this.posX = _posX
    }

    this.setPosY = function(_posY) {
        this.posY = _posY
    }

    this.setAltura = function(_altura) {
        this.altura = _altura
    }

    this.setLargura = function(_largura) {
        this.largura = _largura 
    }

    this.setCtx = function() {
        this.ctx = c.getContext("2d")
    }                
}

let c = document.getElementById("bubble")

let vet = []
let soma = 0
let i = 0 // contador para quantidade de operações a ser realizadas

// Por recomendação do @fernandosavio converti o laço for em uma função que é
//passada como parâmetro para uma requisição de quadros de animação feita
//através do método window.requestAnimationFrame()
function exibirBarras() {
    vet[i] = new Barra()
    let num = Math.floor(random(1,100))
    vet[i].setNumero(num)
    vet[i].setPosX(soma)
    soma += 51
    vet[i].setPosY(0)
    vet[i].setAltura(num + 100)
    vet[i].setLargura(50)
    vet[i].setCtx()
    vet[i].ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    vet[i].ctx.fillRect( 
                        vet[i].posX,
                        vet[i].posY,
                        vet[i].largura,
                        vet[i].altura)            
    i++; // incrementa o contador
    //verifica se o contador atingiu o limite determinado
    if (i < 8) requestAnimationFrame(exibirBarras); // Se ainda não atingir o limite faz a requisição de um novo quadro de animação
}

requestAnimationFrame(exibirBarras);
```

```html
<canvas id ="bubble" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #c6c6c6"></canvas>
```

## Problema com bubble sort

O bubble sort, ou ordenação por flutuação (literalmente "por bolha"), é um algoritmo de ordenação dos mais simples. A ideia é percorrer o vector diversas vezes, e a cada passagem fazer flutuar para o topo o maior elemento da sequência. Essa movimentação lembra a forma como as bolhas em um tanque de água procuram seu próprio nível, e disso vem o nome do algoritmo.

No melhor caso, o algoritmo executa `n` operações relevantes, onde `n` representa o número de elementos do vector. No pior caso, são feitas `n²` operações. A complexidade desse algoritmo é de ordem quadrática. Por isso, ele não é recomendado para programas que precisem de velocidade e operem com quantidade elevada de dados.

O algorítimo do bubble sort é esse aqui:

```
faça
    declare :trocado falso
    para cada elemento no vetor até o penúltimo faça
      se os elementos não estão na ordem certa 
         trocar elementos de lugar
         atribua verdadeiro para :trocado
      fim se
    fim para
fim faça se :trocado for falso
```

## Problema do canvas e interação dinâmica

O elemento HTML `<canvas>` é um elemento que pode ser usado para desenhar gráficos via código (normalmente JavaScript). Por exemplo, ele pode ser usado para desenhar gráficos, fazer composição de fotos, criar animações ou até mesmo fazer processamento ou renderização de vídeo em tempo real.
Pode ser feito mas quando se trata de associar objetos e valores com imagens o canvas não é muito adequado pois tende a se tornar trabalhoso fazer associações entre valores e gráficos pois depois desenhados os elementos são apenas pixels na mídia(ou num vetor de pixels).

Para esse tipo de interação **eu** acho mais fácil usar [`SVG`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG).

## Resposta

Que eu fiz foi trocar o `canvas` por um `svg` para que a troca da posição do elementos se torna-se mais fácil, implementei um algorítimo correto de bubble sort e também adicionei em `Barra` um método para facilitar a troca das propriedades.

```js
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var Barra = function() {
    let numero
    let posX
    let posY
    let altura
    let largura
    //let ctx
    let rect

    // Troca as propriedades de dois elementos
    this.trocar = function(elem) {
        var aux = this.numero;
        this.numero = elem.numero;
        elem.numero = aux;

        aux = this.posX;
        this.posX = elem.posX;
        elem.posX = aux;

        aux = this.altura;
        this.altura = elem.altura;
        elem.altura = aux;


        this.rect.setAttribute('height',this.altura);
        elem.rect.setAttribute('height',elem.altura);

    }

    this.setNumero = function(_numero) {
        this.numero = _numero
    }

    this.setPosX = function(_posX) {
        this.posX = _posX
    }

    this.setPosY = function(_posY) {
        this.posY = _posY
    }

    this.setAltura = function(_altura) {
        this.altura = _altura
    }

    this.setLargura = function(_largura) {
        this.largura = _largura 
    }

    this.setCtx = function() {
        // this.ctx = c.getContext("2d")
    }          

    this.setRect = function(_rect) {
        this.rect = _rect
    }
}

let c = document.getElementById("bubble")

let vet = []
let soma = 0
let i = 0 
let svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function exibirBarras() {           
    vet[i] = new Barra()
    let num = Math.floor(random(1,100))
    vet[i].setNumero(num)
    vet[i].setPosX(soma)
    soma += 51
    vet[i].setPosY(0)
    vet[i].setAltura(num)
    vet[i].setLargura(50)

    //Cria um retangulo em SVG
    vet[i].setRect(document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect'));
    vet[i].rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', vet[i].posX);
    vet[i].rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', vet[i].posY);
    vet[i].rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', vet[i].altura);
    vet[i].rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', vet[i].largura);
    vet[i].rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'red');
                        
    //Adiciona o retangulo ao elemento bubble
    document.getElementById('bubble').appendChild(vet[i].rect);

    i++;
    if (i > 8){        
        bubble(vet);
    } else {
       requestAnimationFrame(exibirBarras);
    }
}    

requestAnimationFrame(exibirBarras);

// Algoritimo de bubble sort segundo o algoritimo já descrito
function bubble(vet) {
    var aux;
    do {
        var trocado = false;
        for(let i = 0; i < vet.length - 1; i++) {
            vet[i].rect.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');

            if (vet[i].numero > vet[i + 1 ].numero) {
                vet[i].trocar(vet[i + 1 ]);
                trocado = true;
            }
            vet[i].rect.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
        }
    } while (trocado);
}
```

```html
<svg id ="bubble" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #c6c6c6"></svg>
```

Comment: Seria interessante você falar sobre [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) onde você fala sobre `setInterval`... Por questões de boas práticas e para o AP conhecer melhores maneiras de animar algo em JS.

Comment: @fernandosavio, Obrigado!! Eu desconhecia o método `windows.requestAnimationFrame()` vou ler a documentação, entender como funciona e  com certeza vou encaixar na resposta.

Comment: Opa.. que bom que pude contribuir então :D

Comment: @fernandosavio, Está ai a resposta atualizada com a sua recomendação. Mais uma vez obrigado pela informação compartilhada.

Comment: Agradeço muito pela resposta Augusto Vasques, exclareceu muitas duvidas que eu estava tendo. Obrigado!